# Compromise between array_merge and array1 + array2

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I want to union two array, override duplicated keys but do NOT want to reindex all indexes. Is there some function which will do that?

I need the union structure of both, so it does not matter which content is in each key.

**Array 1:**

```
[820]
   [name1]
      [id] = "My Name"
   [name2]
      [id] = "Your Name"
[830]
   [id] = "Mothers Name"
```

**Array 2:**

```
[815]
   [name1]
      [id] = "IDs Name"
[820]
   [name1]
      [id] = "Names Name"
   [id] = "Last ID ID"
```

The result should be

```
[815]
   [name1]
      [id] = //does not matter
[820]
   [name1]
      [id] = //does not matter
   [name2]
      [id] = //does not matter
   [id] = //does not matter
[830]
   [id] = //does not matter
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result = array();
foreach ($array1 as $key => $value){
    if(isset($array2[$key]))
        $result[$key] = array_merge($value, $array2[$key]);
    else 
        $result[$key] = $value;
}
foreach ($array2 as $key => $value){
    if(isset($array1[$key]))
        $result[$key] = array_merge($value, $array1[$key]);
    else 
        $result[$key] = $value;
}
```